# Custom Loss Function Returns Graph Execution Error: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 32

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, lstm, loss-function

I have built a loss function which adds time and frequency weighted averages and variances to the MSE:

```
def nuloss(y1, y2, FFT=True):
    S = tf.shape(y1)
    N = tf.cast(tf.reduce_prod(S), tf.float32)
    n = N / tf.cast(S[1], tf.float32)
    if FFT:
        hl = tf.cast(S[2] / 2, tf.int32)
        domain = tf.transpose(tf.concat([tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(time, 0), [hl, 1]), tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(freq, 0), [hl, 1])], axis=0))
    else:
        domain = tf.transpose(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(time, 0), [S[2], 1]))
    W = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(domain, axis=0), tf.float32)
    w = tf.cast(tf.reshape(domain, (1, S[1], S[2])), tf.float32)
    mse = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum((y1 - y2)**2), tf.float32) / N
    wa1 = tf.reduce_sum(y1*w, axis=1) / W
    wa2 = tf.reduce_sum(y2*w, axis=1) / W
    wa = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(wa1 - wa2)) / n
    wv1 = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(((y1 - tf.reshape(wa1, (S[0], 1, S[2])))**2)*w, axis=1) / W)
    wv2 = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(((y2 - tf.reshape(wa2, (S[0], 1, S[2])))**2)*w, axis=1) / W)
    wv = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(wv1 - wv2)) / n
    return mse + wa + wv
```

which I have passed to an LSTM model:

```
def LSTM(inpdata, oupdata, NHLayer=7, LR=0.002, DR=0.2, DS=3):
    inpshape = np.shape(inpdata)[1:]
    oupshape = np.shape(oupdata)[1:]
    Input = keras.Input(shape=inpshape)
    Nnode = [int(round(o)) for o in np.linspace(inpshape[1], oupshape[1], NHLayer)]
    rnn = keras.layers.LSTM(inpshape[1], activation=tf.nn.elu, return_sequences=True)(Input)
    for o, n in enumerate(Nnode):
        rnn = keras.layers.LSTM(max([n, Nnode[0]]), activation=tf.nn.elu, return_sequences=True)(rnn)
        if DR > 0 and o % DS == 0 and o != NHLayer - 1:
            rnn = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=DR)(rnn)
    Output = keras.layers.Dense(oupshape[1], activation=keras.activations.linear)(rnn)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=Input, outputs=Output)
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(LR)
    model.compile(loss=nuloss, optimizer=optimizer, weighted_metrics=['mae'])
    return model
```

When I use my custom loss function, it has no problem returning values. When I pass it to my neural network, I get the following error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[35], line 1
----> 1 modelfit = model.fit(hdata2a, sdata2a, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2, sample_weight=sample_weights_a, epochs=Epochs, callbacks=[early_stop, scheduler], use_multiprocessing=True)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:60, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53   # Convert any objects of type core_types.Tensor to Tensor.
     54   inputs = [
     55       tensor_conversion_registry.convert(t)
     56       if isinstance(t, core_types.Tensor)
     57       else t
     58       for t in inputs
     59   ]
---> 60   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     61                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     62 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     63   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node nuloss/weighted_loss/Squeeze defined at (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/ipython3", line 11, in <module>

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 128, in start_ipython

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 318, in start

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 888, in mainloop

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 881, in interact

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3006, in run_cell

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3061, in _run_cell

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3266, in run_cell_async

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3445, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3505, in run_code

  File "<ipython-input-35-e617bd4a8085>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1783, in fit

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1377, in train_function

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1360, in step_function

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1349, in run_step

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1127, in train_step

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1185, in compute_loss

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 277, in __call__

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 161, in __call__

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/losses_utils.py", line 350, in compute_weighted_loss

  File "/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/losses_utils.py", line 224, in squeeze_or_expand_dimensions

Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 32
     [[{{node nuloss/weighted_loss/Squeeze}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_149960]
```

So what gives? 32 is the default batch size, but I don't know where else that number would factor in here. So really I have no clue what is causing this error.